# What to do when question gets longer and longer

Tags: discussion

I´m concerning to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689928/alternatives-to-for-loop) where OP trumbles over new problems again and again which occur because his/her original question was quite unspecific but answerable. I posted an answer that not only handled the actual problem but also gave a better approach for the user to avoid such situations in the future. However as time goes by OP comes with more and more problems because the data he/she is using might be invalid which was not part of the actual question. Therefor the list of comments concerning those specific problems grows and grows while the actual questions stays uneffected.

I am not really willing to continue this discussion within the chat because I simply do not have the time to do so. Furthermore all those problems could have simply be solved by OP himself by easy debugging as they are far more basic than the actual posted problem. Thus I´m reluctant on helpi him any further as long as there is no own research provided.

Is there anything I can do to avoid those situations? Should I flag those questions although I provided an answer which - as far as I can estimate - handles the main part of the question?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Chameleon-vamp.  Write it off.  Downvote, closevote, move on.

Comment: so, between "all those problems could have simply be solved by the OP himself by easy debugging" and the general vibe of the question here.... this is a chameleon question by an help-vamp..... run away, fast.